# How do I get the list of runs for last 30 days in github actions?

Tags: rest, github-actions, github-api, github-actions-services

How do I modify this API call to get the list of runs for the last 30 days?

Endpoint:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/[OWNER]/[REPO]/actions/runs
```

I tried:

```
https://github.infra.cloudera.com/api/v3/repos/[OWNER]/[REPO]/actions/runs?created=datetime.today() - timedelta(days=30)
```

and it didn't work.

Comment: Are you using Python to generate the date range?

Comment: nope, I'm doing postman call

Comment: These are Python APIs: `datetime.today() - timedelta(days=30)`.

Comment: The date range should be like this `created=START..END`. See https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/getting-started-with-searching-on-github/understanding-the-search-syntax#query-for-values-between-a-range.

Comment: what should start and end date to get API result for last 30 days

Comment: That should be `?created=2023-02-04..2023-03-06`. Python example: https://godbolt.org/z/5hEGd9EMh

Comment: According to [Query for values between a range](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/getting-started-with-searching-on-github/understanding-the-search-syntax#query-for-values-between-a-range), "**You can use the range syntax `n..n` to search for values within a range, where the first number `n` is the lowest value and the second is the highest value.**" i.e. `range=lowest..highest`.

Comment: Either `?created=2023-02-04..2023-03-06` or `?created=2023-02-04..*` should work. Please include any errors that you are getting in your question under an **UPDATE** section. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

With gh cli search for failed actions from the last 30 days and list the ids:

```
gh run list --jq ' .[]| select(.conclusion| contains("failure"))|

            select(.createdAt > (now-( 30 * 86400) | strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%SZ") ))|

            .databaseId' --json conclusion,databaseId,createdAt -R  <[OWNER]/[REPO]>
```

Check the output with:

```
gh run view <id> -R <[OWNER]/[REPO]>
```

Refine fields and conditions for purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for "[Workflow runs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflow-runs?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-workflow-runs-for-a-workflow)":

```
GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/workflows/{workflow_id}/runs
```

With `created` parameter and [`>=YYYY-MM-DD` query](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/getting-started-with-searching-on-github/understanding-the-search-syntax#query-for-dates)

For example, you'd run

```
GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/workflows/{workflow_id}/runs?created=>=YYYY-MM-DD
```

And replace `YYYY-MM-DD` with your datetime output in this format